# Ruby on Rails error: Invalid connection "adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails ( rails version 2.3.4), and using pg gem (version 0.12.2) on Windows.
My database.yml file has the following content:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: canvas4
  username: canvas
  password: canvas
  port: 5433
  timeout: 5000
  pool: 5
  queue:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf8
    database: canvas4_queue
    host: localhost
    port: 5433
    username: canvas
    password: canvas
    timeout: 5000
    pool: 5
```

But when i run command: `bundle exec rake db:initial_setup RAILS_ENV=production`, the error occurs:

`Invalid connection "adapter"`

I've also tried with `gem "activerecord-postgresql-adapter"` but the same error occurs as above.

I can successfully setup with sqlite3 driver.

Do you know how to get postgresql adapter to work with rails 2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your db-adapter in database.yml is set to "postgresql". If still you have the same problem, then try using the pure-ruby adapter:

gem install postgres-pr

(make sure you uninstall the pg gem before... to avoid conflicts)

If it works, then it's a problem with the postgres gem. Anyway, for development purposes, using the pure-ruby gem is usually ok.